# Unable to get mysql count in node.js route

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am new to node.js, and currently working on demo project so my requirement is  to get count of userId which I am calling by function and this function is declared outside of route, but I am getting undefined but in same function getting count values but when  I returned count  still getting undefined in route.

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {      
    const usersQuery = "SELECT * FROM users";
    dbConn.query(usersQuery,function(err,rows)     {
        if(err) {
            console.log('this error',res);
        } else {
            let total=getCount();   // calling function placed outside
            console.log(total);
            }
        
        });
    });
```

Function declared outside to return count:

```
function getCount(){
    const usersQuery = "SELECT count(id) as cnt FROM users";
    dbConn.query(usersQuery,function(err,rows)     {
        if(err) {
            console.log('failed  to get count');
        } else {
            return rows; // retun count 
          
            }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the result of the `query`

```js
function getCount(){
    const usersQuery = "SELECT count(id) as cnt FROM users";
    return dbConn.query(usersQuery,function(err,rows)     {
        if(err) {
            console.log('failed  to get count');
        } else {
            return rows; // retun count
        }
    })
}
```

Note that probably returns a `Promise` you need to handle correctly.

Comment: Your `getCount` didn't return anything. That is why `total` is undefined after `let total=getCount();`. Note the `return` on line 3 in the answer, which returns the result of calling `query`. Try that in your code base and see if/what changes.

Comment: That was a little guessing on my part from my experience. If it's all working as you expected, please ignore that. I was guessing `dbConn.query` returns a `Promise` so potentially you will need to either calling `then` on the `Promise` or `await` on the `Promise`. Using `Promise` is its own topic. If you need to or want to know more about it, there are lots of resources you can Google or just search on SO.

Comment: sorry it is not working

Comment: I noticed other console output so I thought it is working fine, but unfortunately it is returning query error object not count result.

Comment: OK. What error are you getting?

Comment: _callSite: Error
      at Protocol._enqueue (E:\node applications\node_js_crud_operation\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)

Comment: can you please figure out this problem ??

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got the required output by using Promise() in node js

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {      
    const Query = "SELECT * FROM t1";
    dbConn.query(Query,function(err,rows)     {
        if(err) {
            // write some code
        } else {
// call to promise
              getData().then(function (outputVal) {
                console.log(outputVal[0].Usr);
            }).catch(function () {
                // write error here
            });
        }
    
    });
});
```

// Promise code

```
function getData() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //  setTimeout(function () {
        const MQuery = "SELECT count(id) as Usr FROM t2";
        dbConn.query(MQuery , function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                reject();
            } else {
                resolve(rows);
            }
            // }, 1000);
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you should know:

1. The functions declared outside routes will be executed first in stack once the server starts even though you haven't called the specific route yet. By the time you call this function, it already holds `undefined` or `null` depending on the code inside the functions.
2. `dbConn.query()` is Promise. Which means it works synchronously.

if you need count of users, here is what you can do:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {      
    const usersQuery = "SELECT * FROM users";
    dbConn.query(usersQuery,function(err,rows)     {
        if(err) {
            console.log('this error',res);
        } else {
            let total= rows.length // you will get an array of users, therefore the number of users is equal to the length of the array
            console.log(total);
        }
        
   });
});
```